# How to disable cache for a nuxt3 app on netlify?

Tags: caching, nuxt.js, netlify

I have a nuxt app that fetches items from directus.
The app is server side rendered and hosted on netlify.

I have a problem with the home page that gets cached, so it doesn't show the newly added items on Directus.

On the homepage a component fetches the tree latest news articles.
On the news pages, all articles are fetched and displayed.

The problem:
If I create an article in Directus, the homepage doesn't show it. If I then go to the "news" page, the new article is there. If I then go back to the home page, the new article is now showing.
Then, if I refresh the page, the new article doesn't show up again.

I've tried editing the netlify.toml file like this:

```
[[headers]]
for = "/*"
[headers.values]
Cache-Control = "no-cache"
```

or like this:

```
[[headers]]
for = "/*"
[headers.values]
Cache-Control = "max-age=0, must-revalidate, public"
```

But the problem is still there.

Why is the homepage cached, but ot the "news" page? How can I disable the cache for the homepage?
thanks in advance!